# Sizeof pointer for 16 bit and 32 bit

Tags: c, sizeof

I was just curious to know what would the `sizeof` pointer return for a 16 bit and a 32 bit system

```
printf("%d", sizeof(int16 *));
printf("%d", sizeof(int32 *));
```

Thank you.

Comment: On 16 bit it would be 2, whereas on 32 bits would be 4.

Comment: do you means means if `sizeof(void*)` == `8` means its 64-bits and if its `sizeof(void*)` == `4` then 32 bit.

Comment: It is not an answerable question if you are not explicit about the type of system.  16-bit code often had different types of pointers to deal with the restrictions.  Getting 4 would not be unusual.  The size of a pointer is otherwise completely unrelated to the size of the pointed-to object.

Comment: *"I was just curious to know what would the sizeof pointer return for a 16 bit and a 32 bit system"* - Yet your code example doesn't have anything to do with that question at all.

Comment: There is nothing related with `int16` and `int32` because you are passing pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: On a 32bit Intel 386 you will likely see these returning 4, while targeting a 16bit 8086 you might most likely see either 2 or 4 depending on the memory model you selected.

**The details**

First standard C does not mandate anything particular about pointers, only that they need to be able to "point to" the given variable, and pointer arithmetic needs to work within the data area of the given variable. Even a C interpreter which has some exotic representation of pointers is possible, and given this flexibility pointers truly might be of any size depending on what you target.

Usually however compilers indeed represent pointers by memory addresses which makes several operations undefined by the C standard "usually working". The way how the compiler chooses to represent a pointer depends on the targeted architecture: compiler writers obviously chose representations which are either or both useful and efficient.

An example to *useful* representations is generic pointers on a Harward architecture micro. They allow you to address both code and data ram. On a 8 bit micro they might be encoded as one type byte plus 2 address bytes, this obviously implies that whenever you dereference one such pointer, more complex code has to be emitted to load the contents from the proper place.

That gives a good example to an *efficient* representation: why not have specific pointers then? One which points to code memory, an other which points to data memory? Just 2 bytes (assuming 16bit address space as usual for 8bit micros such as the 8051), and no need to select by type.

But then you have multiple types of pointers, eh (again the 8051: you will likely have at least one additional type of pointer pointing within it's internal RAM too...). The programmer then needs to think about which particular pointer type he needs to use.

And of course the sizes also differ. On this hypothetical compiler targeting the 8051, you would have a generic pointer type of 3 bytes, an external data memory pointer type of 2 bytes, a code memory pointer of 2 bytes, and an internal RAM pointer type of 1 byte.

Also note that *these are types of pointers*, and **not** the types of data they point to (function pointers are a little off here as the fact a pointer is a function pointer implies that it is of a different type than data pointers while not having any specific syntax difference except that the data type it points to is a function type).

Back to your 16bit machine, assuming it is a 8086:

If you use some memory model where the compiler assumes you have a single data segment, you will likely get 2 byte data pointers if you don't specifically declare one `near` or `far`. Otherwise you will get 4 byte pointers by default. The representation of 2 byte pointers is usually simply the 16bit offset, while for 4 byte pointers it is a segment:offset pair. You can always apply a `near` or `far` specifier to explicitly make your pointers one or another type.

(How `near` pointers work in an program which also uses `far` pointers? Simply there is a default data segment generated by the compiler, and all `near`s are located within that. The compiler may simply permanently, or at least most of the time, have the `ds` segment register filled with the default data segment, so access of data pointed by `near`s can be faster)

Answer (score -4):

The size of the a pointer depends on the architecture. Precisely, it depends on the size of the addresses used in that architecture which reflects the size of the bus system to access the memory.

For example, on 32 bits architecture the size of an address is 4 bytes :

```
sizeof (void *) == 4 Bytes.
```

On 64bits, addreses have size 8 bytes:

```
sizeof (void *) == 8 bytes.
```

**Note**, that all pointers have the same size interdependently of the type. So if you execute your code, the size of a `int16` pointer and the size of `int32` pointer will be the same.

However, the size of a pointer on a 16 bit system should be 2 bytes. Usually, 16bit systems have really few memory (some megabytes) and 2 bytes are enough to address all its locations. To be more precise, with a pointer of 16 bit the maximum memory you can have is around 65 KB. (really few compared to the amount of memory of a today computer).

Comment: The size of a pointer is chosen by the C implementation. The underlying architecture logically imposes requirements, but it does not make the final decision about the size. The C language was designed to be greatly flexible and has been implemented on many diverse machines and architectures, some of which have unusual addressing features.

Comment: **NO**. Nothing in the C standard mandates that a pointer to `int16` be the same size as a pointer to `int32`.

Comment: 16 bits can have 65k different values, not 65M.